# String vs StringBuilder

Tags: java, arrays, spring, oop, java-8

I have a condition like :

```
public String createId(List<String> list)
{
String id="";
if(list.contains("name"))
id+="TEST VALUE NAME";
if(list.contains("age"))
id+="Test Value AGE";
.
.
. likewise many if condition
return id;
}
```

As per my understanding we should use **StringBuilder** in loop condition and **String** in simple concatenation. So here wanted to ask I should use ***String or StringBuilder***? Kindly suggest

Comment: StringBuilder would be prefered

Comment: You may format your code by indenting it.

Comment: Assuming there’s a large number of these `if` statements, a `StringBuilder` would be preferable, but then, you should also be concerned about these repeated linear searches.

Comment: Even if a `StringBuilder` is preferred over a `String +=` here, the `.contains`, `List` and general structure of the code here are most likely having a bigger impact than `StringBuilder` vs `String`. For example, If all your conditions look like this (each value in the list maps to exactly one value the resulting string), you could just loop trough the List once, add a `switch-case` and concat using a `StringBuilder` in that loop. Or use a `Set`. Each call to `contains` on a `List` has to loop through all elements until it finds the queried value.

Then again, dont do premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

**StringBuilder** is the best for this scenario because it's mutable. the **String** is immutable so when you modify the string it creates a new object.

Comment: Not necessarily.  According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), "To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for the given task it would be better to get rid of the multiple duplicated `if` statements by defining a *list* of the keys to match the input list and use Stream API to generate the string id, e.g. `Collectors.joining` [with delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) or [without the delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--).

Assuming that there is a single rule to create a part of the id: append `"Test Value " + key.toUpperCase()`, the implementation may look as follows:

```java
final List<String> keys = Arrays.asList(
    "name", "age" /* and other needed keys*/
);

public String createId(List<String> list) {
    return keys
            .stream()
            .filter(list::contains)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .map(str -> "Test Value " + str)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("_")); // or Collectors.joining()
}

System.out.println(createId(Arrays.asList("age", "name", "surname")));
// output: Test Value NAME_Test Value AGE
```

---

If custom parts should be provided for `name`, `age`, etc., a `Map` of matches should be prepared and used, also it may make sense to convert the input `list` into `Set<String` to facilitate look-ups:

```java
final Map<String, String> keys = new LinkedHashMap<>(); {
    // fill the map in special order
    keys.put("name", "Name Part");
    keys.put("age", "Test Age");
    /* and other needed keys*/
}

public String createId(List<String> list) {
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(list);
    return keys.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(words::contains) // faster lookup O(1) at the cost of another collection
            .map(keys::get)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("_")); // or Collectors.joining()
}

System.out.println(createId(Arrays.asList("age", "surname", "name")));
// output: Name Part_Test Age
```

Answer (score 0):

In general your understanding is correct about when to use `String` concatenation vs `StringBuilder`. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) says

> To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java
> compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to
> reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by
> evaluation of an expression.

For the larger majority of cases you should use whichever method results in better readability and maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

As already said **StringBuilder** is immutable and **String** is not.

To add to this, when compiler compiles string concatenations it converts it to StringBuilder. [String concatenation in toString in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Something else to keep in mind is that `id+="TEST VALUE NAME";` will add complicity if you do code analysis with Sonar or other tools.

Using StringBuilder will not add complexity with analysis tools.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your first answer! It needs a bit of editing: "StringBuilder is mutable and String is not." And you surely meant "complexity" instead of "complicity."